# In HTML, How do I make a button within a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a button and put an ID in a paragraph to output some text when a function is mentioned, but how to I put a second button/s when i click the first one.
(for example if I click 1-2 it shows button 1 and 2 and 3-4 outputs 3 and 4)
please try to keep it simple if you can explain as i only started programming recently.

I have tried changing the innerHTML in a function script a button uses to code for another button, but that doesn't work.

```
<button class="button" onclick="contact()">Contact</button>
<p id=( "Identifier")></p>
<script>
  function contact() {
    document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = "<button class="
    button " onclick="
    email()
    ">email</button> <button class="
    button " onclick="
    email()
    ">phone</button>";
  }

  function email() {
    document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = "Email here";
  }

  function phone() {
    document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = "Phone here";
  }
</script>
```

When I click a button using above code, two more buttons should show up below it, and when I click them, the result of (in this, email here or phone here) should show, but don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly,** `id` is delcared as `<p id="identifier"></p>` and not <s>`<p id=( "Identifier")></p`></s>. 
**Secondly,** you can use backticks to write multi lined strings.

Modify your code as below please

```js
function contact() {
  document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = `
  <button class="button" onclick="email()">email</button> 
  <button class="button" onclick="phone()">phone</button>`;
}

function email() {
  document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = "Email here";
}

function phone() {
  document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = "Phone here";
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="contact()">Contact</button>
<p id="identifier"></p>
```